# Sound Design cutting throught Music

Tags: sound, music, film, film-sound-design, sound-design

I'm currently working on a project where there is a particular scene where on one hand there is music and at the same time, we should hear heavy reverbered steps.
It getting tough to make the reverb cut throught the music; I can hear it, but not with the full effect the scene requires

Any tips you guys can give me?

Comment: can you provide a short sample of music and reverbered steps?

Comment: Put the reverb mainly in mono on the centre channel?

Comment: Pan music to back speakers and/or pan hard left and hard right to possibly free up center speaker and/or put all reverb in mono.

Comment: Good tips, a delayed reverb may help too.

Answer (score 1):

EQ is your friend here. My first guess would be to EQ the lows and extreme highs out of the reverb return so you can boost it without muddying the whole mix. Similarly, you can use EQ to carve out a spot in the music for your reverb. If you do all of this adjustment while listening in mono, it should retain any corrective action you make when you switch back to stereo.